# DialogFragment with ProgressBar to update when task updates

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialogfragment, android-progressbar

I have an AsyncTask which can publish progress to a main activity.

I also have a DialogFragment with ProgressBar which I create in my main activity.

In the main activity, I first execute the AsyncTask, then create the DialogFragment.

```
processTask = new ProcessImageAsyncTask(dataPathFile, lang, this, tessBaseApi);
processTask.execute(bitmap);

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
DialogFragment dialog = new TessProgressDialog();
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show(fragmentManager, "tessProgress");
```

I would like to update the progress bar when the main activity receives an update from the async task. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Basically I found the solution myself while writing the question, but I couldn't find any other answers, so here it is:

Solution is to override onAttachFragment in the main activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    if (fragment instanceof TessProgressDialog)
    {
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            progressListener = (TessProgressUpdaterInterface) fragment;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(fragment.toString()
                    + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

And the TessProgressDialog would implement TessProgressUpdaterInterface

```
public class TessProgressDialog extends DialogFragment implements TessProgressUpdaterInterface
{
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(int p)
    {
        if(mProgressBar != null)
         mProgressBar.setProgress(p);
    }
}
```

And finally, I have an interface TessProgressUpdaterInterface:

```
public interface TessProgressUpdaterInterface
{
    void onUpdate(int p);
}
```

Now just call the below whenever you receive an update from the async task

```
if(progressListener != null)
    progressListener.onUpdate(progressValues.getPercent());
```